# Distribute Custom Post in different pages

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type and a page where those are shown. I have been asked to make different pages and distribute those already created custom post types but I'm scratching my head a bit about how to achieve that.

The "easy way" would be to create 6 different custom post types, 1 for each new page and re-create the posts which would be a pain. Is there a way to use the already created custom post types and assign them to different pages? Maybe with a category or a custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each one a category or a tag (or, even better, a [custom taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)) and then for each page create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) and do a [custom query](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Taxonomy_Parameters) that loads only those posts with that particular tax.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, I went the taxonomy way, I felt like the right way.